# Can't set the number of paginations with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the numbers of pagination using Javascript. The arrows navigation is working fine but when I try to add the numbers of pages my code doesn't work. I have 2 pages with 10 results each. When I click in the number 1 the console print the number 3. The problem is inside the function createPagination when I create the loop for the page numbers. Any help?

```js
var arrFull = [];
var pageSize = 10;
var pages = -1;
var actualPage = 0;

function changePagination(pagination) {
  if(Number(pagination) !== actualPage && pagination > 0 && pagination <= pages) {
    var start = ((pagination - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
    if(pagination === 1) {
      ini = 0;
    }
    var end = pagination * pageSize;
    if(end > arrFull.length) {
      end = arrFull.length;
    }
    var arr = arrFull.slice(start,end);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      createObject(arr[i]);
    }
    actualPage = Number(pagination);
    createPagination();
  }
}

function createPagination() {
  var paginator = document.getElementById('pagination');
  paginator.innerHTML = "";
  var arrowLeft = document.createElement('a');
  arrowLeft.setAttribute('href', '');
  var arrowRight = document.createElement('a');
  arrowRight.setAttribute('href', '');
  arrowLeft.innerHTML = '<span class="arrow"></span>';
  arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(actualPage - 1);
  });
  arrowRight.innerHTML = '<span class="arrow"></span>';
  arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(actualPage + 1);
  });
  paginator.appendChild(arrowLeft);
  for(var pagination = 1; pagination <= pages; pagination++) {
    var number = document.createElement('a');
    number.setAttribute('href', '');
    number.innerHTML = pagination;
    number.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      changePagination(pagination);
      console.log(pagination);
    });
    paginator.appendChild(number);
  }
  paginator.appendChild(arrowRight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass on your `pagination` variable it passes the last value set to it in that context (the `3` because of its last iteration in the loop).

You should declare a variable inside the `click event` and assign to it the value of `pagination` and then pass your local variable to your method:

```
number.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    let currentPage = pagination;
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(currentPage);
    console.log(currentPage);
});
```

That should do the trick.

---

## Edit

This is the actual solution:

```
number.setAttribute("page", pagination);

number.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let currentPage = +event.target.getAttribute("page");
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(currentPage);
    console.log(currentPage);
});
```

The reason why the number `3` is being returned is because the `let currentPage = pagination;` line is being executed when the event triggers; by that time the value of the variable `pagination` is equal to `3`, so you need to save its value through every iteration (it can be saving it inside a property within your element **outside** of the event scope like so: `number._pageNumber = pagination;`; or as the given example: `number.setAttribute("page", pagination);`).

---

## Full implementation

```html
<html>
<body>

<!--Element to simulate the pagination-->
<div id="pagination"></div>

<script>
var arrFull = [];
var pageSize = 10;
var pages = 2;  // Change to simulate your case (changed the '-1' to '2')
var actualPage = 0;

function changePagination(pagination) {
  if(Number(pagination) !== actualPage && pagination > 0 && pagination <= pages) {
    var start = ((pagination - 1) * pageSize) + 1;
    if(pagination === 1) {
      ini = 0;
    }
    var end = pagination * pageSize;
    if(end > arrFull.length) {
      end = arrFull.length;
    }
    var arr = arrFull.slice(start,end);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      createObject(arr[i]);
    }
    actualPage = Number(pagination);
    createPagination();
  }
}

function createPagination() {
  var paginator = document.getElementById('pagination');
  paginator.innerHTML = "";
  var arrowLeft = document.createElement('a');
  arrowLeft.setAttribute('href', '');
  var arrowRight = document.createElement('a');
  arrowRight.setAttribute('href', '');
  arrowLeft.innerHTML = '<span class="arrow"></span>';
  arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(actualPage - 1);
  });
  arrowRight.innerHTML = '<span class="arrow"></span>';
  arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changePagination(actualPage + 1);
  });
  paginator.appendChild(arrowLeft);
  for(var pagination = 1; pagination <= pages; pagination++) {
    var number = document.createElement('a');
    number.setAttribute('href', '');
    number.innerHTML = pagination;
    
    // <Here_is_the_sugested_code> //
    
    number.setAttribute("page", pagination);

    number.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let currentPage = +event.target.getAttribute("page");
        event.preventDefault();
        changePagination(currentPage);
        console.log(currentPage);
    });
    
    // </Here_is_the_sugested_code> //
    
    paginator.appendChild(number);
  }
  paginator.appendChild(arrowRight);
}

createPagination(); // Call to the function to simulate the generation
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the number 3 in the console @ifebles

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I'm editing the answer with the solution.

Comment: page is not defined @ifebles

Comment: Added the full implementation to the answer @jpcmf80

Comment: My bad, I was missing to pass the page as String in getAttribute. Your answer is correct. Thank you @ifebies.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!